# Joomla single article menu link URL set incorrectly

Tags: joomla3.0

I have a menu item to open one article. When I select an article from the list, Joomla automatically populates URL. But this URL is incorrect.

Example link:
`index.php?option=com_content&view=**profile**&id=39`

But the correct one is:
`index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=39`

Any idea why does this happen?

Thank you.

Comment: Does your menu item really point to the *Single article*? Recreate it [in line with described here](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_a_menu_item_which_points_to_an_Article)

Comment: What extension are you using that introduces profiles? Also, http://joomla.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

If it is problem in URL, you can copy that URL and change the Menu link as external and paste the URL over there.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. But I need Joomla to work correctly without doing work arounds.